# Excel formula to calculate the time a device is on and off

Tags: excel, search, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a dehumidifier that turns on and off.  I want to find out how many minutes it is on and then how many minutes it is off.  I have three cells:

```
A1 - Date 
B1 - Time 
C1 - Status (On or Off)
```

I need a formula that will look in Cell C1 and if it contains "On" then continue looking at all consecutive cells for the last "On" and then calculate the time difference in column B and place this calculated value in column D.  Below I show the calculated minutes in the last row where the status is found, but it doesn't matter if it is the first or last instance of the value "On".  I've got the hard part of calculating the difference in time down.  I need help with the easy part of searching through the consecutive on's and off's and calculating the difference between the times.  I've tried using vlookup, index and match but come up empty each time.  Below is an image of the table.

[image: Sample Data Set]

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: Does every cell increment by 1 minute every time? Or do we have to assume that it might not be set up like that?

Comment: also, in cell D29, it should be 15 min, not 25. No?

Comment: `=IF(C2<>C3,$B2-INDEX($B:$B,LARGE(($C$1:$C2<>$C2)*(ROW($C$1:$C2)),1)+1),"")` maybe this helps you in the right direction. It looks for the start time by searching the row of the end time of the previous value (on/off) in column C and adding one row.

Comment: Depending on what you want for a final report, a Power Query solution might be a good method.

Answer (score 2):

Enter the following formula in Cell D2:

```
=IF(C2=C3,"",ROW(C2)-LARGE(IF($D$1:D1<>"",ROW($D$1:D1)),1)-1)
```

Use the fill handle to drag down.

**Note:** This formula assumes that each row represents **one** minute, and counts accordingly. This will not work if a row skips a minute.

That produces an integer with how many minutes elapsed.
If you want 0:05:00 format, use this formula:

```
=IF(C2=C3,"",(ROW(C2)-LARGE(IF($D$1:D1<>"",ROW($D$1:D1)),1)-1)*0.000694444444444444)
```

Format Column D using this format:

```
[h]:mm:ss
```

Comment: I tried placing this formula in D2 and filling it down: =IF(C2=C3,"",ROW(C2)-LARGE(IF($D$1:D1<>"",ROW($D$1:D1)),1)-1) and I can see that it identifies the last row for a given on or off, but in column D cell it shows #VALUE! instead of the minute difference.  I'll work with this and see if I can figure it out.  Thanks for showing me some light.

Comment: and what happened?